# How to create Recyclerview game time line events

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am developing a Game fans app. I want to create a layout given below

[image]

I have great experience in making custom recycelerviews with multiple LAYOUT_VIEW_TYPES.

My question is this the best way to create that recyclerview or I can do this in more easyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phew... Finally I did it with Recyclerview custom layout items left and right.

Sharing my work.

here is my `layout_item_time_line_left.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".livescore.TimeLineFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_time_line_item_bg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txtPlayerName2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPlayerImage"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_upload_profile"
            app:border_color="@color/white"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:selector_stroke_color="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPlayerName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Neymar"
            android:textColor="#66666a"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgPlayerImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEventName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Goal"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_color_live_score"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgPlayerImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPlayerName" />

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgEventImage"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sports_footbal"
            app:border_width="1dp"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtEventName"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPlayerName"
            app:selector_stroke_color="@color/white" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgEventImage2"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_online"
        app:border_width="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:selector_stroke_color="@color/white" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewLineUpper"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="#41415A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgEventImage2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewLineLower"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="#41415A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgEventImage2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPlayerName2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="33''"
        android:textColor="#66666a"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgEventImage2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is my `layout_item_time_line_right.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_time_line_item_bg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtPlayerName2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPlayerImage"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_upload_profile"
            app:border_color="@color/white"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:selector_stroke_color="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPlayerName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Neymar"
            android:textColor="#66666a"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgPlayerImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEventName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Goal"
            android:textColor="@color/txt_color_live_score"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgPlayerImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPlayerName" />

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgEventImage"
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sports_footbal"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtEventName"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPlayerName"
            app:selector_stroke_color="@color/white" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgEventImage2"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_online"
        app:border_width="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:selector_stroke_color="@color/white" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewLineUpper"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="#41415A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgEventImage2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewLineLower"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="#41415A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgEventImage2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPlayerName2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="33''"
        android:textColor="#66666a"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgEventImage2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is my fragment `fragment_time_line.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#020321"
    tools:context=".livescore.TimeLineFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_border_live_score_tab_table"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtBallPossession"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Ball possession"
                android:textColor="#66666a"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_possession_percentage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtBallPossession"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtLeftPercentage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="70%"
                    android:textColor="#00ffac"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBarLeft"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:indeterminate="false"
                    android:indeterminateTint="#00ffac"
                    android:max="100"
                    android:progress="50"
                    android:rotation="180" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtRightPercentage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="30%"
                    android:textColor="#ff0909"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_card"
                android:clipToOutline="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/img_footbal_ground_green"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_possession_percentage" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_match_timeline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and here is my JAVA code for fragment

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link TimeLineFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class TimeLineFragment extends Fragment {


    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public TimeLineFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment TimeLineFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static TimeLineFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        TimeLineFragment fragment = new TimeLineFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    private View mView;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewMatchTimeline;
    private ArrayList<MatchTimeLine> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_time_line, container, false);

        recyclerViewMatchTimeline = mView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_match_timeline);

        LinearLayoutManager matchTimelineLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerViewMatchTimeline.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewMatchTimeline.setLayoutManager(matchTimelineLayoutManager);

        recyclerViewMatchTimeline.setAdapter(new TimeLineMatchEventsRecyclerViewAdapter(items));

        return mView;

    }
}
```

and lastly my magic Adapter `TimeLineMatchEventsRecyclerViewAdapter.java` (copied from stackoverflow answer)

```
public class TimeLineMatchEventsRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<MatchTimeLine> mModelList;


    public TimeLineMatchEventsRecyclerViewAdapter(List<MatchTimeLine> modelList) {
        this.mModelList = modelList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
        // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
        return position % 2 * 2;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:

                LayoutItemTimeLineLeftBinding bindingLeftView = LayoutItemTimeLineLeftBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
                return new ViewHolderLeft(bindingLeftView);

            case 2:
                LayoutItemTimeLineRightBinding bindingRightView = LayoutItemTimeLineRightBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
                return new ViewHolderRight(bindingRightView);

            default:
                LayoutItemTimeLineRightBinding bindingRightDefault = LayoutItemTimeLineRightBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
                return new ViewHolderRight(bindingRightDefault);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        // final Team team = mModelList.get(position);

        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case 0:
                ViewHolderLeft viewHolderLeft = (ViewHolderLeft) holder;
                break;

            case 2:
                ViewHolderRight viewHolderRight = (ViewHolderRight) holder;
                break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
//        return mModelList == null ? 0 : mModelList.size();
        return 20;
    }

    class ViewHolderLeft extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        LayoutItemTimeLineLeftBinding binding;

        public ViewHolderLeft(LayoutItemTimeLineLeftBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolderRight extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        LayoutItemTimeLineRightBinding binding;

        public ViewHolderRight(LayoutItemTimeLineRightBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output I got

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes the best way to achieve that result is by creating a recyclerview with multiple layouts and I think that it's the only way if you are using xml.

But this could be a lot easier if you make it using `jetpack compose` no need for recycler view or adapter anymore with compose and you can make any custom layout that you want.

Comment: thank you for the direction. can you give a code example for creating atleast single row using the jetpack compose. highly appreciated